# how to make a div slide in from outside of the window, on load (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

My question pretty basic, it's written up there.

How to make a div slide in from outside of the window onload? For example, it may appear from the right side of the window.

And I actually need basic javascript code, not jQuery.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure javascript also.
Create a timer interval. that runs every 1 ms. which modifies the left attribute every time the timer is hit. once the left reaches 0 stop the timer.
--html

```js
var div = document.getElementById("slidingDiv");
div.style.position = "absolute";
var left = document.body.offsetWidth;
div.style.left = left + "px";
var gap = 5;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
  div.style.left = left + "px";
  if (left - gap < 0) {
    left = 0;
  } else {
    left -= gap;
  }
  if (left == 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1);
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="slidingDiv">this div slides</div>
</div>
```

watch a demo in this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/8vr42hq7/).

Answer (score 0):

This forum is not for code requests...

Anyway you can position a html element by using its offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties in javascript.
Also you have to use an interval to make the animation.

```
var target = document.getElementById('div');
var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
   target.offsetWidth++;
   // When the div moved enough...
   if (target.offsetWidth > 300) {
      window.clearInterval(interval);  // ...clear the interval
   }       
}, 500); // The animation step will be done every 500ms -> 0.5s
```

When you are targeting new Browsers (IE9+) you can also look at css transitions with hardware acceleration, which is done like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         .hw-ac {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /* This neat css rule says that the html element will be rendered from the GPU */
            transition: left 1s linear; /* The animation will take 1 second */
         }
         .start-pos { /* The start position outside of the screen */
            position: absolute;
            left: -100px;
         }
         .target-pos { /* The target poition */
            position: absolute;
            left: 200px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div" class="hw-ac start-pos">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now with javascript just replace the class start-pos with the class target-pos:

```
var target = document.getElementById('div');
target.className = 'hw-ac target-pos';
```

Here an example for Firefox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
  #div {
            position: absolute;
   background-color: #f00;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
         .hw-ac {
            -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); /* This neat css rule says that the html element will be rendered from the GPU */
            -moz-transition: left 1s linear; /* The animation will take 1 second */
         }
         .start-pos { /* The start position outside of the screen */
            left: -100px;
         }
         .target-pos { /* The target poition */
            left: 200px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div" class="hw-ac start-pos">
      </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  function start() {
   var target = document.getElementById('div');
   target.className = 'hw-ac target-pos';
  }
   </script>
   <input type="button" onclick="start();" value="PRESS ME" />
   </body>
</html>
```